# How to fake headings or optgroups in dropdownlist in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, html-select

I apologise if this has been posted before, but if so I couldn't find it after much searching.

I was trying to work out how to include optgroups/headings in an asp.net dropdownlist. 
Most answers said just 'no', but I couldn't find an answer that didn't include overriding dropdownlist, which seemed overkill.

When I worked out how simple it was, thought I'd share, in case it helps anyone else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example solution. CSS is inline for clarity.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" >    
   <asp:ListItem style="font-weight:bold; color:black;" disabled="true">Heading 1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem style="font-weight:bold; color:black;" disabled="true">Heading 2</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="21"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="22"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Item 3" Value="23"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

It renders nicely, though some browser differences:
In Chrome & Firefox the headings are nice and black, but I.E. renders as a disabled grey.

Importantly in all of them the headings are unselectable and visually distinct from the items.